# db_select orderRandom With range

Tags: nodes

I'm trying to query a random node from the last 10 that were created.

So far I've used this but it doesn't produce the right results:

```
 $query = db_select('node', 'n');
 $query->fields('n', array('text','created_time'))
   ->orderBy('n.created', 'DESC')
   ->range(0, 10)
   ->orderRandom();
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

How can I get the data I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `node` table doesn't have a `text` or `created_time` column so I'm not sure what data you're trying to select. Regardless, here are a couple of examples that use a subquery to select the `title` and `created` columns for a single random node from a pool of the ten most recent:

1. Subquery in the `FROM`:

   ```
   $subquery = db_select('node', 'n')
     ->fields('n', ['title', 'created'])
     ->orderBy('n.created', 'DESC')
     ->range(0, 10);

   $query = db_select($subquery, 'n2')
     ->fields('n2', ['title', 'created'])
     ->orderByRandom() 
     ->range(0, 1);
   ```

   Which is roughly equivalent to:

   ```
   SELECT n2.title, n2.created 
   FROM (
     SELECT n.title, n.created
     FROM node n
     ORDER BY n.created DESC
     LIMIT 10
   ) AS n2
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 1
   ```
2. Subquery in the `WHERE`:

   ```
   $subquery = db_select('node', 'n2')
     ->fields('n2', ['nid'])
     ->orderBy('n2.created', 'DESC')
     ->range(0, 10);

   $query = db_select('node', 'n')
     ->fields('n', ['title', 'created'])
     ->condition('n.nid', $subquery, 'IN')
     ->orderByRandom()
     ->range(0, 1);
   ```

   Which is roughly equivalent to:

   ```
   SELECT n.title, n.created
   FROM node n
   WHERE n.nid IN (
     SELECT n2.nid
     FROM node n2
     ORDER BY n2.created DESC
     LIMIT 10
   )
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 1
   ```

   And the code:

You could also try a `JOIN` approach, it's worth trying a few methods to see which has the best performance.

Comment: I heard [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x) has better performance.

Comment: Marginally @NoSssweat, but only in terms of a few milliseconds of php time. It can’t speed the query up, just the preparation of the SQL string

Comment: Since I can't edit my previous comment, just stating this for correctness, in this question's case you would use [db_query_range](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query_range/7.x).